# Hide volumeControl on html5 audio tag by css or js

Tags: audio, html5-audio

How to hide controls volume (muteButton & volumeControl) of html5 tag audio, there's no way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share some code that you have tried so that the community can help you.

Comment: there's no code, it's simply tag <audio> html5, i don't know how to hide control volume &  mute control. thank you in advance.